# How to start editing my site with Wordpress?

Tags: customization, editor

I'm new to wordpress and I already read a lot of articles and watched a lot of videos but still can't find a single solution to my problem.

I already bought a hosting and the site is up on the web. Now I need to EDIT IT!
customize the layout.

I have 2 stupid doubts that I couldn't solve by searching in google:

1) Understand the flow of wordpress.
Download the files -> Edit the code -> upload back.
Is it something possible to be done with Github?Heroku?Anything?

2) How things are really done by people that actually work with worpdress? All I see is "drag & drop" tutorials. Is it how things are done with wordpress or do we write the actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress can be used in a variety of ways, so there's no one answer as to how you can do things. In many cases there are multiple ways to achieve the same goal. But, there are common uses:

Non-technical users often install WordPress and then install and configure premade plugins and themes. Themes control the look and feel of a site, while plugins add or change functionality. Usually little to no coding experience is required to use these. In many cases, you can find a way to achieve your goals without having to code anything.

More technical users may want to customize further. If this is the case, it's usually helpful to first try premade themes and plugins to see what they do, and then gradually ease into development. Yes, you can use GitHub - and you can also use FTP or your host's file manager, and a variety of other ways. FTP/SFTP is a very common scenario but not the only one available. Part of it depends too on what your host allows. Right now, there are several major types of code you may wish to explore - themes are primarily made of PHP and CSS; plugins are now split between PHP and JavaScript. That is because WordPress's new editor, the Block Editor, uses primarily JS to create the blocks that you use to build out content.

In any case, any *content* you want to publish is created by logging into your site and adding or editing Posts, Pages, or custom post types. Posts and Pages come standard with WP Core; some themes and plugins add custom post types, and you can also create your own custom post types. Again typically it's best to get used to the Core post types first, and then you can build things out further if needed. In addition to publishing content, many themes also support things like custom menus and widgets. You may just want to start playing around, and possibly create a development site - not the live one, but a local copy - to experiment and see what's possible and what you may want to do.

[WordPress.org documentation](https://wordpress.org/support/category/basic-usage/) is a good place to start.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you so much to take some of your time to answer a newbie!  
So I used to work with vanila html/js/css/php and Laravel, now I'm trying to edit the pages same way as I used to do and I just can't do it.  
I wanted to work with Wordpress because it looked easier to manage posts/comments/etc..  

I was trying to edit the theme that comes with the instalation but I was unable to change position of DOM elements (Menu, header, sidebar, etc...).  Is it possible to do with only HTML/CSS or for this I do need to use WP markup? thank you!

Comment: WordPress themes include a mixture of not only HTML and CSS but also PHP, including WordPress-specific functions. Rather than trying to just dive in and edit you may fare better if you read the Theme Handbook ( https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/ ) so you'll become familiar with some of the WP PHP functions you'll need, and so you can learn to create a child theme. It's never recommended to edit files directly because even themes receive updates, and all your edits will be overwritten - but you can create a child theme so your changes stay even after an update.

Comment: The Template Hierarchy ( https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ ) should help a lot with understanding how themes work. There's no single place to edit where all similar content appears - as in, to move "the sidebar" you're likely to have to touch multiple files, because things like Categories will often have different sidebars than individual Posts, which may be different still from Pages. Absolutely look through the code and move things around and experiment - it just helps to have a basic understanding of where to find things. :)